# pass input parameter of function 1 to function 2 without explicitly passing it as an input to function 2

Tags: r, function, tidyeval

I'm chaining two functions together where both use the same column to perform some operation. I'd like to be able to specify this column as the input parameter only on the call to the first function but also have it accessible within the second function when I pass the output of function 1 into function 2.

The code below demonstrates what I mean and where i'm getting different results from what I want.

```
filter_function <- function(.x, .y){
  .x %>%
    dplyr::filter({{ .y }} != 4)
}

count_function <- function(.x, .y){
  .x %>%
    dplyr::count({{ .y }})
}

filter_function(mtcars %>% as_tibble(), cyl) %>%
  count_function(.)
```

This returns a single value of `21` which is the count of all rows remaining in the tibble after filtering on `cyl != 4`, as per the `filter_function`. But what I want it to output is the same as:

```
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  filter(cyl != 4) %>%
  count(cyl)

# A tibble: 2 × 2
    cyl     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     6     7
2     8    14
```

So is there is a way I can access `.y` in `count_function` (within the context of chaining two functions together like in this example), without explicitly passing it to `count_function` as a parameter?

Comment: Dont know if this helps: I get your desired output if I save the output of `filter_function`, then run `count_function` manually on it. But I think you are asking for a solution that works with the pipe, right?

Comment: I am looking for a piping solution yes. But what code worked for you? I just ran: ```filter <- filter_function(mtcars %>% as_tibble(), cyl) 
count_function(filter)``` and I get the same output as above (`21`). It seems it should be possible to store .y in `filter_function` and then somehow access this in `count_function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** If we reverse the order of the functions then the column of interest will always be first so we won't need to know which one it is:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  count_function(cyl) %>%
  filter_function(.[[1]])
##   cyl  n
## 1   6  7
## 2   8 14
```

**2)** The same idea holds more generally even if we keep the order of the functions:

```
mtcars %>%
  relocate(cyl) %>%
  filter_function(.[1]) %>%
  count_function(.[1])
```

**3)** If the reason to do this is just that `cyl` is  only referred to once to make it easier to change later we could put it in a variable.

```
v <- "cyl"
mtcars %>%
  filter_function(!!sym(v)) %>%
  count_function(!!sym(v))
```

or we could perform the assignment within the pipeline in which case it will not be visible outside the pipeline.

```
mtcars %>% { 
  v <- "cyl"
  filter_function(., !!sym(v)) %>%
  count_function(!!sym(v))
}
```

**4)** It would also be possible to pass information via attributes

```
mtcars %>%
  structure(var = "cyl") %>%
  filter_function(!!sym(attr(., "var"))) %>%
  count_function(!!sym(attr(., "var")))
```

**5)** A dummy column could be used.

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(dummy = "cyl") %>%
  filter_function(!!sym(first(.$dummy))) %>%
  count_function(!!sym(first(.$dummy)))
```

Comment: Cool solution for the specific case i mocked up! I am interested in the more general principle though. Say I wanted to pivot in the first function and then use the same column (or a value of it) in the title of a plot in the second function, for ex

Comment: The same idea holds more generally.  See the addition.

Comment: I see, thanks. This only works for data columns though right? What if it was a  string object which formed part of a variable name, and I wanted to paste it with the rest of the string name in function 1 and then just print it as a string in function 2? Eg, say I wanted to pass ‘“foo_”’ to function 1, and then within that function evaluate it using ‘!!sym(paste0(.y, “bar”))’ and then in function 2, I wanted to make a plot and use the ‘“foo_”’ string as my plot title?

Comment: Have added more options.